# angularjs: Unable to display special characters in input field of type number

Tags: html, angularjs

i am having problem in angularjs in formatting a input field. here's the background

we need a creditcard input textfield which needs to be type="number" so that mobile can show numeric keyboard. On blur event, we need to mask all the digits except last 4.

even though angular ng-model accepts special chars in the model, the value does not get displayed in the input field.

here's the example code illustrated the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="PaymentController">
      Card Number 1:<input type="number" ng-model="ccard1" /> {{ccard1}} <br/>
      Card Number 2:<input type="number" ng-model="ccard2" /> {{ccard2}} <br/>
      Card Number 3:<input type="number" ng-model="ccard3" /> {{ccard3}}    
    </div>
    <script>
      function PaymentController($scope){
        $scope.ccard1=1234;   
        $scope.ccard2='1234';     
        $scope.ccard3='####';             
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

here's the [jsbin demo](http://jsbin.com/fujup/8/edit)

anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: What's the problem - you have `type` set to `number` - it only accepts numbers.

Comment: This is not an AngularJS problem. The browser is the one preventing the mask since the input type is number.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working solution, may not be the right approach.

create a directive and remove the parsers & formatters for that field. one caveat is that form validation wont work, you have to manually validate.

```
paymentApp.directive('rawinput', function(){
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        priority: 100,
        link: function(scope, ele, attr, ngModel){
            ngModel.$parsers=[];
            ngModel.$formatters=[];
        }
    };
});
```

and specify the directive wherever required like this

```
<input type="number" ng-model="ccard3" rawinput/>
```

here's the working demo:  http://jsbin.com/fated/2/edit